# Is there a way to get the config file name specified by --configfile?

Tags: snakemake

I need to get the config file name (along with its path, if any) specified by --configfile on the commandline within Snakefile.  Is there a way to get it without scanning sys.argv?  Thanks.

Comment: The discussion in this issue https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/594/retrieve-value-of-configfile-parameter-in should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, dariober! That's what I was looking for and missed it.

Comment: Whatever is in bitbucket, it's not accessible anymore. Please write a solution

Comment: @count0 I have posted the codes below in case you're still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the page at the following link given by @dariober is no longer accessible, I put the codes here in case some people have the same question.

https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/594/retrieve-value-of-configfile-parameter-in

```
try:
        CONFIGFILE = str(workflow.overwrite_configfiles[0])
except:
        CONFIGFILE = str(workflow.overwrite_configfile[0])
```

CONFIGFILE will contain the whole path of the config file given by --configfile.